# Memory leak in NSMutableArray, NSArray, NSString in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, memory-leaks, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my app, I got Memory leaks in NSMutableArray, NSArray and NSString.

Here is the code.

```
    NSString *subQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM tbl_lang WHERE glossary = '%@'",append1,glossaryName];
    NSArray *subArray1 = [[[self returnExecuteQuery:subQuery] mutableCopy] autorelease];        
    [subArray addObjectsFromArray:subArray1];

    NSString *columnQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select AutoID,%@ from tbl_lang where glossary='%@'",lblshortName.text,glossaryName];
    NSArray *newArray =[[[self returnExecuteQuery:columnQuery] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [langArray addObjectsFromArray:newArray];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[newArray count]; i++) {
        NSString *cellText = [[newArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lblshortName.text]];

        if (cellText != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && ![cellText isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            NSString *decodedString3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cellText cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];

            [tempArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",lblshortName.text, decodedString3]];
        }
        else {
            [tempArray addObject:@"<empty>"];
        }

        NSString *detail = @"_________________";

        for (int j=0; j<[lableNameArray count]; j++) {

            NSString *checkNull=[[subArray1 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j]]];

            if(checkNull != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && checkNull.length > 0)
            {
                NSString *decodedString4 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[checkNull cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
                detail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ : %@ ",detail,[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j],decodedString4];
            }               
        }   
        [detailTextArray addObject:detail]; 

    }
```

When I run in Instruments I got leaks in

-subArray1 in second line.

-detail (NSString) in second for loop.

And subArray and langArray are my global arrays.

If I remove `mutableCopy` from `NSArray *newArray =[[[self returnExecuteQuery:columnQuery] mutableCopy] autorelease];` and `NSArray *subArray1 = [[[self returnExecuteQuery:subQuery] mutableCopy] autorelease];` then subArray and langArray doesnot retain values.

How to avoid memory leak in this code?

Comment: What does `-returnExecuteQuery:` do? Does it return an owned or a non-owned object? Does its contract say anything about return value validity across multiple calls?

Comment: Do you release tempArray? where? Moreover, try to release subArray1 and newArray (instead autorelease them) after the addObjectsFromArray.

Comment: @Fran : I tried to release both Arrays after main for loop but it gives me EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error for subArray and langArray.

Comment: @Bavarious : `returnExecuteQuery` gives me NSArray fatched from database.

Comment: i got same warning... here is my screenshot and [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166915/memory-leak-how-to-stop) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olease try this one, in above code you are creating two many objects that belong to autorelease pool here is one version where I tried to handle release of those string variables.

Second this is that the leak of `detail` is because you are **de-referencing** it many times in your code. And for `subArray1` please see the comment

```
    NSMutableString *subQuery =[ [NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM tbl_lang WHERE glossary = '%@'",append1,glossaryName];
   // please make returnExecuteQuery's returned array autorelease if it is not.  
   NSArray *subArray1 = [[self returnExecuteQuery:subQuery] mutableCopy] ;
    [subArray addObjectsFromArray:subArray1];

    [subQuery release]; 
    NSMutableString *columnQuery ==[ [NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select AutoID,%@ from tbl_lang where glossary='%@'",lblshortName.text,glossaryName];
    NSArray *newArray =[[self returnExecuteQuery:columnQuery] mutableCopy] ;
    [langArray addObjectsFromArray:newArray];
    [columnQuery relese];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[newArray count]; i++) {
        NSMutableString *tempKey = [[NSMutableString  alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",lblshortName.text]];


        NSString *cellText = [[newArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:tempKey];
        [tempKey release];

        if (cellText != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && ![cellText isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            NSString *decodedString3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cellText cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
            NSMutableString *tempString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",lblshortName.text, decodedString3]];

            [tempArray addObject:tempString];
            [tempString release];
        }
        else {
            [tempArray addObject:@"<empty>"];
        }

        NSMutableString *detail = nil;

        for (int j=0; j<[lableNameArray count]; j++) 
        {
             detail = [[ NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"_________________"];
            NSMutableString *key = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            NSString *checkNull=[[subArray1 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:key];
           [key release];

            if(checkNull != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && checkNull.length > 0)
            {
                NSString *decodedString4 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[checkNull cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
                [detail setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ : %@ ",detail,[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j],decodedString4]];
            } 
              [detailTextArray addObject:detail]; 
              [detail release];              
        }   


    }
    [subArray1 release];
    [newArray release];
```

`UPDATE` : Please do read comments in the code and reply back so that things could be improved.

```
    NSMutableString *subQuery =[ [NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT %@ FROM tbl_lang WHERE glossary = '%@'",append1,glossaryName];
   //*****NOTE THIS POINT ----> please make returnExecuteQuery's returned array autorelease if it is not.  
   NSArray *subArray1 = [[self returnExecuteQuery:subQuery] mutableCopy] ;
    [subArray addObjectsFromArray:subArray1];

    [subQuery release]; 
    NSMutableString *columnQuery ==[ [NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select AutoID,%@ from tbl_lang where glossary='%@'",lblshortName.text,glossaryName];
    //*****NOTE THIS POINT ----> please make returnExecuteQuery's returned array autorelease if it is not.  
    NSArray *newArray =[[self returnExecuteQuery:columnQuery] mutableCopy] ;
    [langArray addObjectsFromArray:newArray];
    [columnQuery relese];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[newArray count]; i++) {
        NSMutableString *tempKey = [[NSMutableString  alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",lblshortName.text]];


        NSString *cellText = [[newArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:tempKey];
        [tempKey release];

        if (cellText != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && ![cellText isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            NSString *decodedString3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cellText cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
            NSMutableString *tempString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",lblshortName.text, decodedString3]];

            [tempArray addObject:tempString];
            [tempString release];
        }
        else {
            [tempArray addObject:@"<empty>"];
        }

        NSMutableString *detail =  [[ NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"_________________"];

        for (int j=0; j<[lableNameArray count]; j++) 
        {

            NSMutableString *key = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            NSString *checkNull=[[subArray1 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:key]; //also here if you note you are using subArray1 not subArray?
           [key release];

            if(checkNull != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && checkNull.length > 0)
            {
                NSString *decodedString4 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[checkNull cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
                [detail setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ : %@ ",detail,[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j],decodedString4]];
               break;//I am not sure why you are checking this condition but assume that you want to get NOT NULL VALUE and  add it to array?
            } 

        }   
        [detailTextArray addObject:detail]; 
        [detail release];              

    }
    [subArray1 release];
    [newArray release];
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
if(checkNull != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && checkNull.length > 0)
            {
                NSString *decodedString4 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[checkNull cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
                [detail appendFormat:@"%@\n%@ : %@ ",detail,[lableNameArray objectAtIndex:j],decodedString4]];

            }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for code, but still there are some issues, I want to add `[detailTextArray addObject:detail];                [detail release];` after for loop,  it shows leak in `detail`. subArray1 and newArray still shows leak in Instruments.

Comment: Please see above code and also answer the comments in the code so that scenario could be more cleare. thanks

Comment: In First and second comments : Arrays are autorelease. and Third comment : I am checking condition for null or blank values. If checknull is not blank or null it should append in detail string with `\n`. So that I can display it in cell's detail text.

Comment: @Meghan, I have updated the code for detail string append operation. Please make sure that you are releasing arrays correctly

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is causing the memory leak, but this may help.  This is a more direct way of copying the arrays, and may result in avoiding the leak:

```
NSArray *langArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [self returnExecuteQuery:columnQuery] copyItems: YES];
```

This basically makes a one-level deep copy of the array returned by returnExecuteQuery.  You can read about it in more detail in [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW1).

I'm not sure how mutableCopy works and that may have something to do with the leak.  If it copies the objects in the old array & then adds them to the new array, they may enter the array with a retain count of 2 (1 from the copy, and 1 from being added to an array.)  It doesn't make much sense that it should work this way.  But, if it does, that could account for the leak.

Comment: @ salo.dm : Thanks for your reply. It help me in some cases. It still shows leak in `detail`, `subArray1` and `newArray`.

Comment: If you use this code, you won't need newArray.  You can delete the entire line referring to newArray.  Similarly, you can do away with subArray1 by replacing the 2nd & 3rd lines in your code with the following:  NSArray *subArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [self returnExecuteQuery:subQuery] copyItems: YES];

Comment: dm: every time when this method call it adds new buch of data in langArray. so this will not help me

Answer (score 0):

You could start by releasing your tempArray once done with it (after the loops).

Often, the higher levels leaks are hidden in the flood of lower level ones (ie a container leaking causes all its content to be leaked as well), which might be the case for your string.

Using `mutableCopy] autorelease];` is fine by the way.