# Memory leak : How to stop?

Tags: database, ipad, memory-leaks, stringwithformat

[image: You can see that memory leak error]
 I am using NSObject class to get all the data from a database. When I call that function it will show a memory leak where I assign a string using stringWithFormat. I think when we use this method we should not have to release that string so why does it show a memory leak?

Thanks in advance. :)

```
- (void) Allnote
{
   [app.NoteArray removeAllObjects];
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes.sqlite"];
   if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
   {
      NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * From note" ];
      const char *sql = [querySQL UTF8String];
      sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            noteClass *noteObj = [[noteClass alloc]init];

            noteObj.noteTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];   // at this place
            noteObj.noteContent = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 1)]; // at this place

            NSNumber *noteId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(searchStatement, 2)];

            noteObj.noteId = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%@"),noteId]; // at this place

            files=noteObj.noteTitle;
            filescont=noteObj.noteContent;
            [app.NoteArray addObject:noteObj];
            [noteObj release];

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);

}

sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: noteId - is property of noteClass instance? Do you reload it's implementation, maybe you write some custom setter for it and do something wrong with memory there?

Comment: noteObj is NSObject type class and noteId is field of that class..and NSNumber *noteId is one variable for holding the value of id of database field and that noteId i am assign to noteObj.noteId....is that any problem with same name ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, `stringWithFormat`is a factory method means that it has autorelease in its definition, that's why u r getting memory issue. But, that is not an issue.its 100% perfect.

Comment: As I have said that u r getting leak in ur code due to factory method but it is not any issue.You need not to worry about that.

Comment: i added screen shot. so now you can check exactly where it shows memory leak warning...this is perfect but why it shows me memory leak error !!

Comment: that's is due to autorelease. see, leak shows that u have not release the allocated memory for that object. But, due to autorelease that will be done at a later stage.so, u r getting leak massage but u need not to worry about that.

Comment: what that purple bar indicates..??

Comment: that issue u will get, but u need not worry for that. Or, if u don't want any issue go for Gomathi's answer.u won't get any issue then.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't apply a format, then why use `stringWithFormat`

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * From note" ];
```

Is the same as:

```
NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * From note";
```

And you are correct, you do not have te release them.

Answer (score 1):

I am responding in addition to Surya Kant's answer.

It was not a problem with that. But still if you want to avert the issue, please do onething.

Instead of the following line,

```
noteObj.noteTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];   // at this place
```

do as follows

```
NSString *noteTit = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];
noteObj.noteTitle = noteTit;
[noteTit release];
```

Similarly do it for others.

Comment: noteObj.noteTitle = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];
               [noteObj.noteTitle release];
                
as you suggest i do that still warning for memory leak :(

Comment: Just check in the Instruments who (which library) is responsible for the leak.

Comment: Then it is not your fault. Foundation library will handle that.